# In R, how to program the for loop to rerun when the result is NA?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, statistics-bootstrap

Hi I'm using a for loop in R to generate a series of numbers, calculate an estimate of interest based on these numbers each time and store all iterations of the estimate of interest in a vector. At times the estimate of interest would be NA depending on the numbers generated during that iteration. Is there a way to ask the for loop to re-run itself when the estimate of interest is NA?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you provide some example data with the code you are using.

Comment: There are many potential ways to approach this and I agree with @akrun, it would be much easier to help you with something to work with. I figure you need your vector to reach a predetermined length?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the for loop inside a while loop. For example:

```
while(is.na(result))
{
    # for loop goes here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still there is some idea in this answer but the other way around : in the `for` loop, `while the estimate is NA`, do the instructions...